# How to set the don't fragment (DF) flag on a socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, packet

I am trying to set the DF (don't fragment flag) for sending packets using UDP.

Looking at the Richard Steven's book Volume 1 Unix Network Programming; The Sockets Networking API, I am unable to find how to set this.

I suspect that I would do it with setsockopt() but can't find it in the table on page 193.

Please suggest how this is done.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You do it with the `setsockopt()` call, by using the `IP_DONTFRAG` option:

```c
int val = 1;
setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DONTFRAG, &val, sizeof(val));
```

[Here's](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/apis/ssocko.htm) a page explaining this in further detail.

For Linux, it appears you have to use the `IP_MTU_DISCOVER` option with the value `IP_PMTUDISC_DO` (or `IP_PMTUDISC_DONT` to turn it off):

```c
int val = IP_PMTUDISC_DO;
setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &val, sizeof(val));
```

I haven't tested this, just looked in the header files and a bit of a web search so you'll need to test it.

As to whether there's another way the DF flag could be set:

> I find nowhere in my program where the "force DF flag" is set, yet `tcpdump` suggests it is. Is there any other way this could get set?

From this excellent page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/7/ip):

> `IP_MTU_DISCOVER:`  Sets or receives the Path MTU Discovery setting for a socket. When enabled, Linux will perform Path MTU Discovery as defined in RFC 1191 on this socket. The don't fragment flag is set on all outgoing datagrams. The system-wide default is controlled by the `ip_no_pmtu_disc` `sysctl` for `SOCK_STREAM` sockets, and disabled on all others. For non `SOCK_STREAM` sockets it is the user's responsibility to packetize the data in MTU sized chunks and to do the retransmits if necessary. The kernel will reject packets that are bigger than the known path MTU if this flag is set (with `EMSGSIZE`).

This looks to me like you can set the system-wide default using `sysctl`:

```c
    sysctl ip_no_pmtu_disc
```

returns `"error: "ip_no_pmtu_disc" is an unknown key"` on my system but it may be set on yours. Other than that, I'm not aware of anything else (other than `setsockopt()` as previously mentioned) that can affect the setting.

Comment: Which level is that under, IPPROTO_IP?

Comment: Is there any other way this could get set?  I presume that by default DF is off, right?

Comment: I think it's off by default but you can use a getsockopt (surprisingly enough :-) to get it's current value.

Comment: IP_DONTFRAG is not supported for multicast and i think its not well supported for UDP sockets outside the BSD implementations. If you are not already getting a EOPNOTSUPP error, you can check with a getsockopt after the setsockopt to confirm its done.

Comment: The IP_DONTFRAG is not defined (compiler error) for my Centos 4 system.  Further, I find nowhere in my program where it is set, yet tcpdump() suggests it is set, and I got a 'message too long' (90) EMSGSIZE error suggesting that it is on too and a packet was too large suggesting that the routing changed mid transfer after many successful packets to a route with a smaller MTU.

Comment: The EMSGSIZE in this condition implies you are trying to send a packet larger than your MTU with the don't fragment bit set. Check your packet size is within MTU.

Comment: Note that fragmentation is triggered when the MTU size is crossed. At this time if DF is set, you typically get a EMSGSIZE.

Comment: It should be supported in BSD *and* Unix98, but I'm not sure if Linus was that concerned with meeting standards :-) I also cannot find it on my Linux system despite having the other options.

Comment: On Centos 4 doing 'sysctl ip_no_pmtu_disc' I get:

  error: 'ip_no_pmtu_disc' is an unknown key

Comment: Then I don't know why it's being set by default. My suggestion is to unset it using the setsockopt() shown in the answer before using the socket.

Comment: Note: for Windows (XP and later) the value is called IP_DONTFRAGMENT. See http://www.nil.si/ipcorner/IP_Fragmentation/

Comment: Silly question; Where do you set the `IP_DONTFRAG` option?  I am using Ubuntu, and I assume this is a parameter in a file.  I don't know where the file is.

Comment: FYI, the correct sysctl check is: sysctl net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working in Userland with the intention to bypass the Kernel network stack and thus building your own packets and headers and hand them to a custom Kernel module, there is a better option than `setsockopt()`.

You can actually set the DF flag just like any other field of `struct iphdr` defined in `linux/ip.h`. The 3-bit IP flags are in fact part of the `frag_off`
 (Fragment Offset) member of the structure.

When you think about it, it makes sense to group those two things as the flags are fragmentation related. According to the [RFC-791](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt), the section describing the IP header structure states that Fragment Offset is 13-bit long and there are three 1-bit flags. The 
`frag_off` member is of type `__be16`, which can hold 13 + 3 bits.

Long story short, here's a solution:

```
struct iphdr ip;
ip.frag_off |= ntohs(IP_DF);
```

We are here exactly setting the DF bit using the designed-for-that-particular-purpose `IP_DF` mask.

`IP_DF` is defined in `net/ip.h` (kernel headers, of course), whereas `struct iphdr` is defined in `linux/ip.h`.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the paxdiablo's answer.

- setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MTU_DISCOVER, &val, sizeof(val))

where `val` is one of:

> ```
> #define IP_PMTUDISC_DONT   0    /* Never send DF frames.  */
> #define IP_PMTUDISC_WANT   1    /* Use per route hints.  */
> #define IP_PMTUDISC_DO     2    /* Always DF.  */
> #define IP_PMTUDISC_PROBE  3    /* Ignore dst pmtu.  */
> ```

- `ip_no_pmtu_disc` in kernel source:

> ```
> if (ipv4_config.no_pmtu_disc)
>     inet->pmtudisc = IP_PMTUDISC_DONT;
> else
>     inet->pmtudisc = IP_PMTUDISC_WANT;
> ```

Comment: So `IP_PMTUDISC_DO` means always Don't Fragment?

Comment: Just to be explicit about the `ip_no_pmtu_disc` setting -- it's not the same values of 0 - 3! Note that "0" means `IP_PMTUDISC_WANT` (a value of 1).