# How to set the Don't Fragment (IP_DF) flag in C

Tags: c, macos, sockets, unix, raw-sockets

I want to set the Don't Fragment flag on a IP packet. Is there a way to do so via the `setsockopt()` function or via the flags of the `sendto()` function?

Can I do this with "normal" sockets or do i have to use raw sockets and build the entire IP header myself, setting it's offset-field to `IP_DF` (which is defined in ip.h)?

Comment: In a comment on the current answer, poster pointed out they were using OS X.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP Don't fragment bit on Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415725/ip-dont-fragment-bit-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://as400bks.rochester.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/apis/ssocko.htm), you can set the `IP_DONTFRAG` option for IP layer, with datagram sockets (UDP). [This SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973439/how-to-set-the-dont-fragment-df-flag-on-a-socket) points in a similar direction.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm developing on Mac. All these constants are defined in the file in.h. Unfortunately, I can't find neither the IP_DONTFRAG nor the IP_MTU_DISCOVER constant. Most (or all) of the other constants, however, are there - for example IP_MULTICAST_TTL and so on. Any idea about this issue on Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers` I did find some constants:

```
netinet/ip.h
99:#define IP_DF 0x4000                    /* dont fragment flag */
netinet6/in6.h
547:#define IPV6_DONTFRAG           62 /* bool; disable IPv6 fragmentation */
```