# IP Don't fragment bit on Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, tcp, ip

I am writing a file transferring program over TCP.

I want to set the don't fragment flag on IP

On a socket this is what I want to do:

```
int val = 1;
setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DONTFRAG, &val, sizeof(val));
```

However `IP_DONTFRAG` does not seem available on Mac OS.  Am I missing something? or did I forget to include it correctly?

Thanks in advance if anyone knows

--Sam

Answer (score 2):

google brought up this: http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2006/Jul/msg00014.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the next message in that thread states that this only works with RAW sockets, which isn't what the poster is asking for: http://lists.apple.com/archives/macnetworkprog/2006/Jul/msg00017.html

Comment: right, I see that now. thanks. but then the following reply indicates that there may be no other way to do it.

Comment: I saw that but I was hoping to avoid having to use raw sockets.  I think it must be possible because when I catch packets on my network the data transfer over tcp mecanism that os x uses itself has that flag on.  I'm guessing that they do that to gain some speed and it would suit my current sending mecanism.

Answer (score 1):

The DF bit is typically used for [path MTU (PMTU) discovery](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1191.txt) automatically by the operating system with TCP connections. If anything, you may have a socket option for disabling PMTU discovery which will have the effect of never setting DF (it's the IP_MTU_DISCOVER socket option on linux). If you leave PMTU discovery on, it will have the effect of always setting DF.

It wouldn't make sense to set/unset it on a packet-by-packet basis because you're using TCP and TCP operates on segments, not packets. If you want to set packet-level stuff, you need to use a lower-layer protocol.

Comment: That is not true for cases like VPN i.e. TCP-over-TCP

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers` it seems to be called `IP_DF` here:

```
netinet/ip.h
99:#define IP_DF 0x4000                    /* dont fragment flag */
netinet6/in6.h
547:#define IPV6_DONTFRAG           62 /* bool; disable IPv6 fragmentation */
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Don't Fragment` bit is typically set on all TCP packets anyway.  You don't have to do any special to achieve this.