# Disable Path MTU discovery on per socket on OS X

Tags: macos, sockets, networking, network-programming, ip

Is there a way to disable Path MTU discovery on per socket basis on OS X?

[This is how to set don't fragment bit on socket on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973439/how-to-set-the-dont-fragment-df-flag-on-a-socket)

But `IP_MTU_DISCOVER` is not recognized on OS X.

Only recognized options as per `netinet/in.h` on OS X are:

```
/*
 * Options for use with [gs]etsockopt at the IP level.
 * First word of comment is data type; bool is stored in int.
 */
#define IP_OPTIONS      1    /* buf/ip_opts; set/get IP options */
#define IP_HDRINCL      2    /* int; header is included with data */
.....
```

Comment: Whosoever voted it to close, care to explain why its not programming related?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP Don't fragment bit on Mac OS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415725/ip-dont-fragment-bit-on-mac-os)